# Basic question about coefficients of the Taylor expansion at $x+\varepsilon$

Tags: taylor-expansion

The Taylor series of a function $f(x)$ at a point $a$ is

$$f(a) +\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots\tag 1$$

So how can, for a small $\varepsilon,$ the value of $f(x+\epsilon)$ be approximated by (and this is the correct way, presumably):

$$f(x+\varepsilon)=f(x)+f'(x)\varepsilon+f''(x)\varepsilon^2+\cdots\tag 2$$

as in [this youtube](https://youtu.be/4YPfFGRw_iI):

[image]

?

Writing a series such as...

$$f(x) +\frac{f'(x)}{1!}(x)+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}(x)^2+\cdots$$

leaving the derivatives of $f(x)$ as a function of $x$ defeats the purpose of getting real coefficients of a polynomial, and it probably makes no sense.

And if the idea is that $a=x+\varepsilon$ for any $x$ the expansion would make sense with the derivatives being evaluated at $f(x+\varepsilon)$ as in

$$\begin{align}
f(x+\varepsilon)&=\small{f(x+\varepsilon)+f'(x+\varepsilon)\left(x-(x+\varepsilon)\right)+f''(x+\varepsilon)(x-\left(x+\varepsilon)\right)^2+\cdots}\\
&=f(x+\varepsilon)+f'(x+\varepsilon)\left(\varepsilon\right)+f''(x+\varepsilon)\left(\varepsilon\right)^2+\cdots
\end{align}$$

instead of $f(x)$ as in Eq (2).

Comment: You want $x = a + \epsilon$, not $a = x + \epsilon$.

Comment: The $a$ in the first formula is what's called $x$ in the second formula. $\epsilon$ in the second formula is $x-a$ in the first formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jack M and Ethan Bolker, and so to close the loop, the equivalence between

$$f(\color{red}x)=f(\color{red}a) +\frac{f'(\color{red}a)}{1!}(\color{red}{x-a})+\frac{f''(\color{red}a)}{2!}(\color{red}{x-a})^2+\cdots\tag {1}$$

and

$$f(\color{blue}x+\color{blue}\varepsilon)=f(\color{blue}x)+\frac{f'(\color{blue}x)}{1!}\color{blue}\varepsilon+\frac{f''(\color{blue}x)}{2!}\color{blue}\varepsilon^2+\cdots\tag 2$$

is:

$$\begin{align} \color {blue} x &=\color {red} a\\
\color{blue} \varepsilon &= \color{red}{x-a} 
\end{align}$$

Hence, the Taylor expansion becomes:

$$f(x+\varepsilon)=f(\color{blue}x) +\frac{f'(\color{blue}x)}{1!}(\color{blue} \varepsilon)+\frac{f''(\color{blue}x)}{2!}(\color{blue} \varepsilon)^2+\cdots$$

---

Of note, there is a missing $\frac{1}{2!}$ in the original YT video for the third term of the Taylor expansion.